# Removed files count - exporting results to file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

can you please help with this one. I'm trying to delete .docx files from path c:\temp with this script

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\' *.docx | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

next I want to export results to mylog.txt can you advise how to do that? I have tried to add |out-file c:\temp\mylog.txt bu this is not working

Comment: Have a look at what `Start-Transcript` does. Use the command `help Start-Transcript -Full`.

Comment: What exactly do you want in "mylog.txt"? Please add expected output.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\' *.docx | Tee-Object -FilePath c:\temp\mylog.txt -Append | Remove-Item`

Comment: or do `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\temp\' -Filter '*.docx' -File | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName | Add-Content -Path 'C:\temp\removedDocuments.txt' ; Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\*" -Include "*.docx" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |  Out-File "C:\temp\ListofDocxFiles.txt" -Force
Remove-Item -Path "C:\temp\*" -Force -Include "*.docx"
```

Directory with *.docx files before script is run:

[image]

Directory with log file after script execution:

[image]